# Send Keys from range value sending random values

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm running into some strange issues.  I'm using VBA Selenium to edit QBO.

I am finding QBO_Current and updating with Sub_ and adding the PARENT_ (sub product of).

The script is looping properly - however - sometimes the line of code in the screenshot is pasting random characters as shown in the screen shot "Value_entered".  If I manually cycle through the section of code below a few times - it will eventually enter the correct values.  Any thoughts?

Also - sometimes the first line doesn't actually select the value in the element.  Any better ideas for selecting all the contents of an element and deleting them reliably?

```
obj.SendKeys obj.Keys.Shift & obj.Keys.Home
obj.Wait 100
obj.SendKeys obj.Keys.Delete


obj.SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUB_STEP1").Cells(script_row, SUB_).Value
```

code

[image: 1]

Script_Row

[image: 2]

Value_entered

[image: 3]

I have manually looped the script and it works sometimes.  I would expect it to enter the value from the script_row consistently into the element

Comment: It looks like Shift key is pressed. All digits are changed to the `Special Characters`.

Comment: Are you operating upon a website? Is QBO a web html element? What kind (html type) is it? Can you show the code that sets the "obj" element?